# Concat strings in multiple columns without duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data like below:

```
# df
Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4
AAA
AAA    AAA    BBB
AAA    CCC
```

I want to concat them without duplicates.

```
Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4   COMBINE
AAA                         AAA
AAA    AAA    BBB           AAA/BBB
AAA    CCC                  AAA/CCC
```

The code I tried:

```
df["COMBINE"] = df[df.filter(regex='^Col',axis=1).columns].apply(lambda x: '/'.join(pd.unique(x)),axis=1)
```

But I got:

```
Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4   COMBINE
AAA                         AAA/
AAA    AAA    BBB           AAA/BBB/
AAA    CCC                  AAA/CCC/
```

Comment: Chain your solution with `.str.strip()` would work for this data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happen because you have empty string in your columns, you can change code like below and get waht you want:

```
>>> df.replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)
>>> df["COMBINE"] = df[df.filter(regex='^Col',axis=1).columns].apply(lambda x: '/'.join(x.dropna().unique()),axis=1)

>>> df

Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4   COMBINE
AAA                         AAA
AAA    AAA    BBB           AAA/BBB
AAA    CCC                  AAA/CCC
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df['Combine'] = df.apply(lambda x: '/'.join(x.dropna().unique()), axis=1)
```

**Note**: if you have empty string instead of `NaN`, then do: `df.replace('', np.nan).apply(...)`.

Output:

```
  Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Combine
0  AAA  None  None   NaN      AAA
1  AAA   AAA   BBB   NaN  AAA/BBB
2  AAA   CCC  None   NaN  AAA/CCC
```

Comment: You edited very good , lol ;))

Answer (score 1):

You could cleanup after:

```
df['Combine'] = df.fillna('').apply('/'.join, axis=1).str.replace('/+(?=/|$)', '', regex=True)
```

How it works:
If one or several `/` are followed by another `/` or the end of line -> remove

```
[AAA, None, None, NaN] -> [AAA, '', '', ''] -> AAA/// -> AAA
```

output:

```
  Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4      Combine
0  AAA  None  None   NaN          AAA
1  AAA   AAA   BBB   NaN  AAA/AAA/BBB
2  AAA   CCC  None   NaN      AAA/CCC
```